# How to remove default back navigation button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a navigation controller to my login screen. Upon user sign in, the view will get redirected to another viewcontroller called `DetailVC`.

If the user has been previously logged in the user will automatically navigate to `DetailVC`. This part works perfectly. However, the default back button in the navigation controller appears on `DetailVC`. How can i remove it ?

On the `DetailVC` i will be navigating to other views, and the navigation back button should be displayed from that point onwards. I only want it to disappear on `DetailVC`. How can i get this done ?

[image]

Comment: you can hide the navigation bar itself.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Or else:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the navigation bar, but this seems like working around a problem created rather than avoiding the problem.

It might be more correct to separate your application into two parts: login and logged in.

In your app delegate on load I would create the login controller as a separate item and your DetailVC as a separate item. Put the DetailVC as the root controller of UINavigationController.

Something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{ 

  // Create login and logged in controllers as properties.
  self.loginController = ... // Use storyboard or however you init this
  self.detailVC = ...        // Use storyboard or however you init this
  self.loggedInController = ... //UINavigationController with root as self.detailVC

  // Check for logged in
  if (self.loggedIn){
    [self switchToLoggedIn];
  }
  else{
    [self switchToLogin];
  }
}

- (void) switchToLogin{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.loginController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) switchToLoggedIn{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.loggedInController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

In your login code you can ask the app delegate instance to switch to the logged in controller once authenticated and on logout switch to the login controller.

As the logged in controller is a UINavigationController it will start as the root properly with no back button.

---

Another simpler but similar option is to modally present your DetailVC in a UINavigationController from the login. As it is the start of a new stack, it will have no back button. To logout, simply dismiss the controllers navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Rory's answer, but in a similar vein, instead of pushing your new view controller when the login completes, consider instead:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[ myDetailVC ] animated:YES];
```

This will replace your root view controller (login) with the new one, and thus there will be no back button.